# Yandex tiles wrong?

Tags: maps, yandex

Are Yandex map tiles wrong or am I missing something? They seem to have an offset compared to all the other map providers (OpenStreet, Google, Bing). 
Google: http://mts0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@279000000&hl=ro&x=33&y=21&z=6&scale=1
Bing: http://t3.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/r120203.jpeg?g=3045&mkt=en-GB&shading=hill
OpenStreet: http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/6/33/21.png
Yandex: http://vec03.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=map&x=33&y=21&z=6&lang=en_US&scale=1
[image]

LE: I found out Yandex is using another projection system...But I'm still stuck

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Comment: Seems like Yandex has it right, seeing as the earth is an ellipsoid, and the others are wrong since they can't (or won't) use an elliptical projection :)

Answer (score 4):

Yandex is using elliptical Mercator projection, unlike Google and OSM using spherical projection, although all of them are using *elliptical* coordinates (WGS84).

Yandex Maps API v2 or higher allows you to work in any projection you need or even combine layers in different projections.

http://api.yandex.com/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/ref/reference/Layer.xml see first example.

Comment: I'm using Telerik for Silverlight which doesn't have this type of projection. And I have to make it from zero...

Comment: @Sergey The link in your answer is outdated. Does Yandex Maps API allow to get tiles as shown in the question via the XYZ protocol?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Nope, Yandex allows access to tiles via client APIs (JS API in this case) only.